# Invoke batch file in .msi or .exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, cmd

I have a requirement which needs a batch script to be invoked before the .msi or .exe package can deploy files to the desired location. I created a setup project and I am ablr to get a .msi and .exe when I build it. My main concern here is that, when I run the exe or msi, the installer deploys the code to the desired location but I have to stop the service brfore copying and start it back after the files are copied. Is there anyway that I can invoke a batch scrip to stop the service before the files are deployed and then invoke another batch script after the files are deployed. I tried using custom action but didnt work, any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF & ECHO This is an Install.bat
NET STOP "the service"
START /WAIT "Installation in progress..." "The installer.msi"
NET START "the service"
```

Comment: Yes. I already have this script. How do I invoke it in a .msi or .exe file with Visual studio 2010 setup project?